# Postgres jsonb_array_elements() returns "cannot extract elements from a scalar", even when given a valid JSON array?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb, jsonb-array-elements

I have a table in postgres called day, which contains a jsonb column called plan_activities.

I have a day record with day.id = 18 and plan_activities contains the following JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "activity": "Gym",
    "cardio": false,
    "strength": true,
    "quantity": 20,
    "units": "mins",
    "timeOfDay": "Evening",
    "summary": "Gym - 20 mins - Evening",
    "timeOfDayOrder": 4
  },
  {
    "activity": "Walk",
    "cardio": true,
    "strength": false,
    "quantity": 15,
    "units": "minutes",
    "timeOfDay": "morning",
    "summary": "Walk - 15 minutes - Lunchtime",
    "timeOfDayOrder": 1
  }
]
```

When I execute the following query:

```
select jsonb_array_elements(day.plan_activities) as activities 
from day 
where day.id = 18;
```

I get the following error:

> Failed to run sql query: cannot extract elements from a scalar

The JSON contains a valid JSON array as far as I can tell. What am I doing wrong?

My eventual goal if I can extract this list is to create separate records elsewhere, each of which contains all the fields plus a reference back to the day record.

Comment: Are there any nulls? `select plan_activities from day where id = 18 and plan_activities is null`

Comment: Would you show us your table schema, please? `\d+ day` in psql.

Comment: Your JSON syntax is ok, and I tried your Json via using `jsonb_array_elements` this is works. May be `where day.id = 18` gets another record which doesn't have Json array. The function `jsonb_array_elements` gets error when your Json string has not Json arrays.

Comment: No nulls found running select plan_activities from day where id = 18 and plan_activities is null. id is a primary key in this case.

Comment: (
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    created_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT 'now()',
    summary_plan text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    summary_day text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    date date,
    total_minutes smallint DEFAULT '0'::smallint,
    cardio_minutes smallint DEFAULT '0'::smallint,
    strength_minutes smallint DEFAULT '0'::smallint,
    day_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    plan_activities jsonb,
    plan_activities_text text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT day_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

Comment: I deleted all records in the table except for the one with id = 18 and got the same error

Comment: It's possible the whole data structure was accidentally added as a single JSON string. See the update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you try to treat a JSON scalar, like a single string or number, as an array.

```
-- ERROR:  cannot extract elements from a scalar
select jsonb_array_elements('23'::jsonb);
```

One of the rows of your query does not contain a JSON array.

Check with `select plan_activities from day where id = 18`. Although `id` is normally a unique primary key and it should be impossible to have more than one row returned.

---

Another way this could happen is if the JSON structure was accidentally added as a single JSON string.

```
-- 1, 2, 3
select jsonb_array_elements('[1, 2, 3]'::jsonb);


-- Note the extra quotes.
-- ERROR:  cannot extract elements from a scalar
select jsonb_array_elements('"[1, 2, 3]"'::jsonb);
```